# Using CSS and JavaScript optimization in SharePoint 2013 results with error on SPRequestModule.IsExcludedPath

Tags: javascript, css, .net, sharepoint, optimization

I'm trying to use [built-in dot.net 4.5 feature web optimization](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/11/27/new-bundling-and-minification-support-asp-net-4-5-series.aspx) (CSS and JavaScript minification) on SharePoint 2013 website and I'm having an exception on ~ urls:

> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: virtualPath
>
> Source Error:  An unhandled exception was generated during the
>   execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin
>   and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: virtualPath]
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPRequestModule.IsExcludedPath(String
>   virtualPath) +278
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPVirtualPathProvider.DirectoryExists(String
>   virtualPath) +57
>   System.Web.Optimization.BundleHandler.RemapHandlerForBundleRequests(HttpApplication
>   app) +136
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +182    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +165
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18408

**Any idea how to solve this?**

***!!! UPDATED ON 12-03-2014!!!***

**First problem solved! now we get error 404.0 from server upon performing GET action to the bundle.**

Here's the code for skipping SharePoint virtual path validation mechanism:

**ApplicationStartModule.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;

namespace Matrix.SharePoint.Publishing.HttpModules
{
    public abstract class ApplicationStartModule : IHttpModule
    {
        private readonly static object _mutex = new object();
        private static bool _initialized = false;

        protected abstract void OnStart();

        public void Init(HttpApplication application)
        {
            if (!_initialized)
                lock (_mutex)
                    if (!_initialized)
                        Application_Start();
        }

        private void Application_Start()
        {
            _initialized = true;
            OnStart();
        }

        public void Dispose() { } 
    }
}
```

**RootVirtualPathProvider.cs**

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web.Hosting;

namespace Matrix.SharePoint.Providers
{
    public class RootVirtualPathProvider : VirtualPathProvider
    {
        public override string CombineVirtualPaths(string basePath, string relativePath)
        {
            return Previous.CombineVirtualPaths(basePath, relativePath);
        }

        public override System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjRef CreateObjRef(Type requestedType)
        {
            return Previous.CreateObjRef(requestedType);
        }

        public override bool FileExists(string virtualPath)
        {
            string patchedVirtualPath = virtualPath;

            if (virtualPath.StartsWith("~/layouts", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                patchedVirtualPath = virtualPath.Remove(0, 1);
            }

            return Previous.FileExists(patchedVirtualPath);
        }

        public override System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency GetCacheDependency(string virtualPath, System.Collections.IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies, DateTime utcStart)
        {
            return Previous.GetCacheDependency(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies, utcStart);
        }

        public override string GetCacheKey(string virtualPath)
        {
            return Previous.GetCacheKey(virtualPath);
        }

        public override VirtualDirectory GetDirectory(string virtualDir)
        {
           return Previous.GetDirectory(virtualDir);
        }

        public override VirtualFile GetFile(string virtualPath)
        {
            return Previous.GetFile(virtualPath);
        }

        public override string GetFileHash(string virtualPath, System.Collections.IEnumerable virtualPathDependencies)
        {
            return Previous.GetFileHash(virtualPath, virtualPathDependencies);
        }

        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a best practice how to use built-in .NET 4.5 web optimization in SharePoint 2013?